# Problema Validacion Login PHP AJAX JS

Tags: php, jquery, html, sql, ajax

estoy desarrollando un sistema para practicar pero se me generò un problema con el Login, puesto que utilizando un script de validacion mediante AJAX enviando a travez de del metodo GET una variale a un Switch y un condicional no logro el efecto deseado ya que al pulsar el submit redirecciona a la pagina del sistema asi el usuario sea inexistente, es decir no existe validacion. aqui el codigo que estoy utilizando.

```
//Funcion para verificar el acceso al sistema

 public function verificar($login,$password){
    $sql="SELECT idusuario,nombre,tipo_documento,num_documento,tlf,email,cargo,imagen,login FROM usuario WHERE login='$login' AND password='$password' AND condicion='1'";

    return executeQuery($sql);
}
```

Case del SWITCH

```
case 'verificar':
    $logina=$_POST['logina'];
    $passworda=$_POST['passworda'];

    //Hash SHA256 en la contraseña
    $passwordhash=hash("SHA256",$passworda);

    $rspta=$usuario->verificar($logina, $passwordhash);

    $fetch=$rspta->fetch_object();

    if (isset($fetch))
    {
        //Declaramos las variables de sesión
        $_SESSION['idusuario']=$fetch->idusuario;
        $_SESSION['nombre']=$fetch->nombre;
        $_SESSION['imagen']=$fetch->imagen;
        $_SESSION['login']=$fetch->login;
    }

        echo json_encode($fetch);
        break;
```

Script de Validacion

```
 $("#frmAcceso").on('submit',function(e)
{
 e.preventDefault();
logina=$("#logina").val();
passworda=$("#passwora").val();

$.post("ajax/usuario.php?op=verificar",
    {"logina":logina,"passworda":passworda},
    function(data)
{
    if (data!="null")
    {
        $(location).attr("href","views/pages/categoria.php");            
    }
    else
    {
        bootbox.alert("Usuario y/o Password incorrectos");
    }
});
})
```

HTML DEL FORMULARIO

```
<form method="post" id="frmAcceso">
            <div class="form-group has-feedback">
                <input type="text" id="logina" name="logina" class="form-control" placeholder="Usuario" required>
                <span class="fa fa-user form-control-feedback"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group has-feedback">
                <input type="password" id="passworda" name="passworda" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required>
                <span class="fa fa-key form-control-feedback"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-8">
                </div>
                <!-- /.col -->
                <div class="col-xs-4">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-flat">Ingresar</button>
                </div>
                <!-- /.col -->
            </div>
        </form>
```

al presionar el boton submit me envia a 'categoria.php' sin importar que datos se pongan en el formulario

Comment: Haz un console log de data a ver qué te devuelve. Saludos!!

Comment: El console Log no me arroja nada, en cambio probe de manera individual el switch  y si me trae los datos , o me arroja el null en caso de no hacer match, el tema es que el data aparentemente se carga de informacion que no es null , y me redirecciona .. seguramente tengo algo mal en el Js pero no se que es puesto que he tratado de utitlizar todo como la documentacion me lo indica.

Comment: Ya probaste haciendo un console.log() de data antes de tu condición solo para verificar que te está devolviendo?

Comment: console.log(data); no te muestra nada? Es raro, ya que si viene relleno, debería mostrar algo

Answer (score 1):

## Primer detalle

Estas utilizando una metodología poco eficiente, ya que estás empleando código de más que pudieses simplificar facilmente, tanto para leerlo como para el tiempo de respuesta. Te voy a demostrar porque.

#### PHP

En tu función de `verificar()` puedes realizar completamente el paso de verificar si existe un usuario o no de la siguiente forma con mysqli:

```
public function verificar($login, $password){
   $handler = mysqli_connect('db_servidor', 'db_usuario', 'db_pass', 'db_nombre');
   $password = hash('sha256', $password);
   $query = "SELECT * FROM usuario WHERE login='$login' AND password='$password' AND condicion='1';";
   $result = mysqli_query($handler, mysqli_real_escape_string($handler, $query));
   return (mysqli_num_rows($result) == 1);
}
```

La funcion `mysqli_real_escape_string()` filtra la cadena para evitar inyecciones SQL.

La funcion en si regresaría un valor booleano dependiendo si el usuario existe o no. Y ya con ello puedes tomar las acciones necesarias y evitas el switch.

```
if($usuario->verificar($login, $passwordhash)){
   $usuario->cargarDatos($login);
   echo 'true';
}else{
   echo 'false';
}

function cargarDatos($usuario){
   $query = "SELECT * FROM usuario WHERE login='$usuario';"
   $result = mysqli_query($handler, mysqli_real_escape_string($handler, $query));
   $data = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
   $_SESSION['idusuario']=$data['idusuario'];
   $_SESSION['nombre']=$data['nombre'];
   $_SESSION['imagen']=$data['imagen'];
   $_SESSION['login']=$data['login'];

}
```

Dando por entendido que guardes `$handler = mysqli_connect('db_servidor', 'db_usuario', 'db_pass', 'db_nombre');` en un lugar apto para el ambito global de tus funciones, solo necesitarias declararlo una vez.

#### JavaScript

Como ya realizamos un proceso de hashing en el lado de PHP, solo haremos lo correspondiente a manejar el evento del clic en el boton.

```
$("#frmAcceso").on('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    logina = $("#logina").val();
    passworda = $("#passwora").val();
    $.ajax({
        data: {
            "logina": logina,
            "passworda": passworda
        },
        url: 'ajax/usuario.php?op=verificar',
        type: 'post',
        beforeSend: function() {
            //Lo que quieras hacer mientras carga la respuesta...
        },
        success: function(response) {
            //En PHP muestras el codigo javascript que quieras ejecutar.
            if(response == true){
               $(location).attr("href","views/pages/categoria.php");
            }else{
               bootbox.alert("Usuario y/o Password incorrectos");
            }
        },
        error: function() {
            //En caso de error 
        }
    });
});
```

## Segundo detalle

Te recomiendo que en la estructura de tu base de datos utilices nombres descriptivos en los campos que tienes, por ejemplo..

```
TABLE usuarios
id
usuario
password
etc
```

Y lo mismo con tus variables, que en lugar de que uses `$login` para el nombre de usuario, utilices `$usuario`. Esto sera un beneficio para ti mismo mas adelante, ya que te ayudara a comprender el codigo cuando necesites modificarlo.

## Tercer detalle

Para tus peticiones AJAX dentro de tu aplicacion, te recomendaria que hicieras un solo archivo PHP (ej. ajax.php) en tu directorio principal y que por medio de un tipo GET enviaras la operacion que quieres hacer. (Ej. ajax.php?verificar, ajax.php?eliminar)

Y dentro de tu archivo PHP lo manejas asi:

```
if(isset($_GET['accion'])){
    //Acciones
}
```

Todo esto para tu propio beneficio, ya que seras tu mismo quien depure el codigo mas tarde y tendras que volverlo a analizar paso a paso para saber como modificarlo.

Answer (score 0):

Creo que este if te está redirigiendo directamente:

```
if (data!="null")
    {
        $(location).attr("href","views/pages/categoria.php");            
    }
```

Tal vez puedas intentar poner en dicho *if* el enlace al método de verificación, y desde allí mostrar la vista "categoria.php" una vez se verifiquen los datos.
No sé mucho de ajax, pero a veces el navegador guarda en caché los scripts, verifica que esté ejecutando el último que guardaste.

Comment: la cuestion es que en teoria, solo si el data fuese diferente de null, es decir la consulta sql le retorno un valor ( pudo lograr un macht en la BD ) deberia de redireccionar,aparentementeese if no esta funcionando porque aun si cambio la condicion del _if_ a un _data="null"_ me redireccioa igual. pero a mi parecer todo me parece correcto .

Comment: null !== "null" !== undefined verifica que tipo de dato es el que te devuelve la respuesta.